# Homomorphisms between groups of Hermitian type and Hodge type and orthogonality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

By a group of Hermitian type I mean a real group $H$ with a maximal compact subgroup $K$ such that $H/K$ is Hermitan Symmetric domain.  A real group $W$ is called of Hodge type if the associatd complex group $G$ admits an action of $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ such that $W$ is preserved by $U(1)$ and the action of $-1$ on $G$ is a Cartan involution. These definitions can be found in Simpson's article "Higgs bundles and local sytems". Now let $h:H\to G$ be a homomorphism of real algebraic groups where $H$ is a group of Hermitian type and $G$ is a group of Hodge type. Let $K$ be the maximal compact subgroup. Is it true that the tangent bundle of $H/K$ lies necessarily in the horizontal subbundle of the tangent bundle of $G/K$ and that it decomposes to an orthogonal direct sum? I will appreciste any Useful references on this problem.

Comment: Could you define "group of Hodge/Hermitian type"? the terminology is not standard and not included in basis linear algebraic group textbooks.

Comment: I mean the ones according to Simpson's definition, I will add this to my question.

Comment: For Hermitian: are you sure that "maximal abelian" is not "maximal compact"? (otherwise $SL_2(\mathbf{R})/SO(2)$ and its powers seem to be the only examples). And is $H$ semisimple? For Hodge type: is "Admiral" a typo?

Comment: Yes you are right i meant maximal Compact subgroup. If it helps we can assume for the moment that $H$ is semisimple. Thanks. I edited the typo!